# What should I return in this method?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to make an algorithm to return a matrix that I have still not processed, but can't seem to find the correct data type...

Here's the code:

```
package com.premiumminds.internship.motionblur;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

/**
 * Created by aamado on 05-05-2021.
 */
class MotionBlurSingleThread implements MotionBlurFactory {

  /**
   * Method to start processing the data
   * 
   * @param data            matrix of integers
   * @param numberOfWorkers number of threads that should work in parallel
   * @return matrix of integers
   */
  public Future<int[][]> run(int[][] data, int numberOfWorkers) {
    
      int[][] temp = new int[data.length][data[0].length];
      
      for(int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; row < data[0].length; col++) {  
          // TO BE DONE
      }
      }
    
      return temp;
      
}
}
```

I can't seem to  return a Future<int[][]> type either...

How do I make this fucntion work? What data type should I return, and how do I go about declaring it?

Comment: Say you have a Callable that does the calculation `calc`, and an ExecutorService `exec`, you could write `Future<...> f = exec.submit(calc);`.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you actually need a `Future`? You could just return the `temp` variable and declare the function as such:

```
public int[][] run(int[][] data, int numberOfWorkers) {

  int[][] temp = new int[data.length][data[0].length];
  
  for(int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; row < data[0].length; col++) {  
      // TO BE DONE
    }
  }

  return temp;  
}
```

If you *do* need  a `Future`:

1. Check the documentation for [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).
2. Observe that it's an interface and you would need to return a concrete type.
3. Review the documentation of the known sub-types to see which works for you.
4. Return an instance of that sub-type.

For example, using [FutureTask(Runnable, V)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#FutureTask(java.lang.Runnable,%20V)):

```
public Future<int[][]> run(int[][] data, int numberOfWorkers) {

  int[][] temp = new int[data.length][data[0].length];
  
  for(int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; row < data[0].length; col++) {  
      // TO BE DONE
    }
  }

  return new FutureTask<int[][]>(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
      }},
         temp);
}
```